# Setup of socket.io with express framework -> How to solve an uncaught ReferenceError?

Tags: node.js, visual-studio, socket.io

I am getting started with node.js/express/socket.io and am having issues making the whole thing work. Not sure it is important but I am using an Express4 TypeScript project from Visual Studio 2022.

Apologies in advance for the long question but I spent a long time doing investigations and sharing what I found out so far may very well save you some time.

The symptoms are:

- Chrome + MS Edge: I have the below 3 error messages (although only the first 2 are about socket.io)
  [image: 3 error messages]
- Firefox : Only the uncaught ReferenceError is there.
  [image: Single error message]

In all 3 browsers, http://localhost:3000/socket.io/socket.io.js shows the scripts successfully. The error/warning mention retrieving that file through port 1337 though.

That leads me to 2 questions:

1. How come the Chromium-based browsers report they are unable to find the socket.io script file whereas Firefox does not?
2. What can I do to make the errors disappear.
   I suppose, maybe incorrectly, that the uncaught ReferenceError is related to that line in the webpage: `var socket = io();`

Notes:
Because of the starting sentence of [Handling CORS](https://socket.io/docs/v4/handling-cors/#configuration) ("*Since Socket.IO **v3**, you need to explicitly enable Cross-Origin Resource Sharing (CORS).*"), I checked the [change log](https://socket.io/docs/v4/changelog/) page and figured my attempt with socket.io years ago, from which the below code was copied, was on socket.io v2. That would explain why it used to work, but no more does (additionally, the listening channel was on `var port = process.env.PORT || 3000;`, which now makes node.js crash completely with `EADDRINUSE: address already in use`).

I visited many questions on SO, socket.io and elsewhere, to no avail. I did not check when browsing but I assume most are **not** applicable to socket.io v3 and later.

Here is my code (developed under Visual studio):

`index.ts`

```js
import express = require('express');

var app = require('express')();
var http = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(http);
var port = 3000;

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html');
});

io.on('connection', function (socket) {
    console.log('New user connected');
    socket.on('disconnection', function () {
        console.log('User disconnected');
    });
    socket.on('chat message', function (msg) {
        io.emit('chat message', msg);
    });
});

http.listen(port, function () {
    console.log('listening on *:' + port);
});

const router = express.Router();
router.get('/', (req: express.Request, res: express.Response) => {
    res.render('index', { title: 'Express' });
});
export default router;
```

`index.html` (generated from a `.pug` file)

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Express</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/stylesheets/main.css">
</head>
<body>
    <ul id="messages"></ul>
    <form id="form" action="">
        <input id="input" autocomplete="off">
        <button>Send</button>
    </form>
    <script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
    <script>
        var socket = io()            ;
        var form = document.getElementById('form');
        var input = document.getElementById('input');

        form.addEventListener('submit', function(e) {
          e.preventDefault();
          if (input.value) {
            socket.emit('chat message', input.value);
            input.value = '';
          }
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

---

Edit: What I am really after is astandalone solution.

4 years and 2 major version later, the socket.io website suggests this is still possible, see:

- [Handling CORS](https://socket.io/docs/v4/handling-cors/#configuration)
  That page starts with the following sentence:

  > Note: this also applies to localhost if your web application and your server are not served from the same port

  ```js
  const io = new Server(httpServer, {
    cors: {
      origin: "http://localhost:8080"
    }
  });

  httpServer.listen(3000);
  ```
- AFAICT, the client code ([here](https://socket.io/docs/v4/client-installation/#standalone-build)) could not be more straightforward and appears to match my code too.

  ```js
  <script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
  <script>
    const socket = io();
  </script>
  ```

I could not find a mention of a weird trick to put things together. Yet,
I tried to modify my server code as above (with `cors: { origin: http://localhost:8080"}` and `cors: { origin: "http://localhost:1337" }` since the latter is the port my http server listen to), I still get error 404.

Comment: Firefox indeed report the missing file in the yellow line

Comment: Ok read again your question and I think we can't help you without a usable codebase to test. Please create a project on Code sandbox or somewhere else where we can test and correct. Because port 1337 and Cors doesn't make sense, in your case. And I think your express server might be miswritten.

Comment: @davidonet I have created this [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/p/devbox/so-fix-socket-io-d2jmpk?file=%2Findex.html). The only thing I am getting now though, is an error `[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...`, which I do not know the cause of.

Comment: I fix the sandbox, it works.
Please accept my answer so I can get the bounty :-)

Comment: Unfortunately, I do not see what you changed. Just to be sure I wasn't missing anything, I copiedg the code from codesandbox to my visual studio but it yields the same error. In fact, in all 3 forks I can see, the line `const router = express.Router();` is missing so I do not see what you have tested to say it now works. Had you edited your answer below with the complete code or given explanations, I most likely could have  tried and confirmed.

Comment: Even though it works, I was not completely satisfied by the other answer;I think it is missing some details about why the example on socket.io website does not work for me and could be simplified a bit for my use case (getting started with node.js). The bounty expires in < 1 day, so if I can suggest you edit your answer to put your full working code in it with a short explanation of the  thing I did wrong, that would be perfect.

Comment: Sorry I yet spent too much time on your problem, I can not make you understand without some effort on your side.

Comment: I think you need some basic understanding of nodejs/npm first and http/express then learn about websockets mechanism before going to socket.io

Answer (score 1, accepted):

error 404 indicated that the browser is unable to find the socket.io.js file.

Socket.io server exposes its clientside js file, try using that.

here is your client.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Express</title>
</head>
<body>
    <ul id="messages"></ul>
    <form id="form" action="">
        <input id="input" autocomplete="off">
        <button>Send</button>
    </form>
    <script src="http://localhost:3000/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
    <script>
        var socket = io('http://localhost:3000', {
            transports: [ 'websocket' ],
            'reconnection': true,
            'reconnectionDelay': 500,
            'reconnectionDelayMax': 1000,
            'reconnectionAttempts': 100
        });
        socket.on('connect', onConnect);
        socket.on('disconnect',onDisconnect);

        function onConnect(){
            console.log('Connected Successully...'); 
        }
        function onDisconnect(){
            console.log('Client disconnected');
        }

        var form = document.getElementById('form');
        var input = document.getElementById('input');

        form.addEventListener('submit', function(e) {
          e.preventDefault();
          if (input.value) {
            socket.emit('chat message', input.value);
            input.value = '';
          }
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

regarding CORS, you should implement CORS and for production maybe you want to implement further security then use the helmet(or ignore the helmet and remove it)

```js
const express = require('express');

var app = require('express')();
var http = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(http);
var port = 3000;

const cors = require('cors');
const helmet = require("helmet");

app.use(cors({
    origin: ['http://localhost:3000/','https://your-host.com/', 'https://your-host-2.com/']
}));

// if you need to implement a content security policy and want to override
app.use(
    helmet({
        contentSecurityPolicy: {
            directives: {
                frameAncestors: [
                    'https://your-host.com/',
                    'https://your-host-2.com/'
                ]
            }
        },
        frameguard: false,
        crossOriginResourcePolicy: { policy: "cross-origin" },
        crossOriginEmbedderPolicy: false,
    })
);

app.use((req,res,next) =>{
    //res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin','*');
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers','origin, x-requested-with, Content-Type, Accept, Authorization');
    if(req.method==='OPTIONS'){
        req.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods','GET,POST,PATCH,DELETE,PUT');
        return res.status(200).json({});
    }
    next();
});


app.get('/', function (req, res) {
    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html');
});

io.on('connection', function (socket) {
    console.log('New user connected');
    socket.on('disconnect', function () {
        console.log('User disconnected');
    });
    socket.on('chat message', function (msg) {
        io.emit('chat message', msg);
    });
});

http.listen(port, function () {
    console.log('listening on *:' + port);
});

const router = express.Router();
router.get('/', (req,res) => {
    res.render('index', { title: 'Express' });
});
//export default router;
```

in the server pay attention to a commented line

```js
//res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin','*');
```

for testing only (not for production), you can simply ignore everything and enable this to avoid all CORS and security.

Comment: If I may, it should be `socket.on('disconnect')`. There is apparently no `disconnection` synonymous for `disconnect`. Anyway, thank you for the hard work, I will let you know beg. next week if I end up facing another wall, although at first glance, it appears functional.

Comment: it should be socket.on('disconnect'), basically, i copied your main code and did not pay attention to this part. :) , more over i will strongly recommend, separating APIs and Socket.io server, that is creating 2 independent projects( socket.io separate and APIs separate), this may give you more flexibility and control.

Comment: Right.... it must have been a thing on v2. Do you mean all the HTTP/HTML in 1 project and the socket.io part in another? How to include the latter into the former?

Comment: @Atmo I could not understand your question "How to include the latter into the former?",  but if you are asking about sending a message from the client to other connected clients, you need to see socket.emit(socket.id) and socket.to("room1").emit(room) and socket.broadcast.emit( .... .. see v3 cheatcheet. https://socket.io/docs/v3/emit-cheatsheet/

Comment: Because you are saying APIs and socket.io should be separated, but I suppose the events/messages managed by socket.io must be imported into the API part for it to broadcast the messages, right?

Answer (score 0):

Ok I fix the codesandbox the following way :

In package.json, express and socket.io libraries are missing

```json
{
  "name": "nodejs-sandbox",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "Node.js example server starter project",
  "license": "MIT",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "nodemon index.js"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "Ives van Hoorne",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/node": "^20.10.5",
    "nodemon": "^3.0.3"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "express": "^4.18.2",
    "socket.io": "^4.7.4"
  }
}
```

Then run `npm install`

In index.js, remove router block as it's useless in your case `app.get("/", ...` does the job

```js
const express = require("express");

var app = require("express")();
var http = require("http").Server(app);
var io = require("socket.io")(http);
var port = 3000;

app.get("/", function (req, res) {
  res.sendFile(__dirname + "/index.html");
});

io.on("connection", function (socket) {
  console.log("New user connected");
  socket.on("disconnection", function () {
    console.log("User disconnected");
  });
  socket.on("chat message", function (msg) {
    console.log("message: " + msg);
    io.emit("chat message", msg);
  });
});

http.listen(port, function () {
  console.log("listening on *:" + port);
});
```

I added a `console.log` on message reception so we can see it works.

index.html remain unchanged.

Comment: Thx but this too gives me 404 errors, which I thought could be related to CORS. I believe there is a built-in way (that is what I want to use) to have the file retrieved from my node server ([link](https://socket.io/docs/v4/handling-cors/)) so I tried to explicitly enable it as instructed,then copy/paste the code under "*this also applies to localhost if your web application and your server are not served from the same port*" hoping the rest of the code would follow (my client code is a replica of [this](https://socket.io/docs/v4/client-installation/#standalone-build)). It did not work...

Comment: Also, just a comment: https://socket.io/get-started/chat#integrating-socketio mentions a CDN can be used but this is only a tip, not a recommendation: the primary example still is with `/socket.io/socket.io.js`.

Comment: I don't think it's a CORS issue you would have a CORS error in the console and CDN are meant to be used by any host.

Comment: Don't be confused by socketio lib loading and websockets connection.